# O processo de automatizar é considerado um produto ou serviço?

Tags: significado, palavra-para-ideia

Estou a desenvolver a seção de um sistema que contém a seguinte estrutura:

[image]

Contudo, preciso incluir uma nova classe que englobe as peças para automação de persianas ou cortinas.

Pensei em:

[image]

Seria  correto considerar **Automação** como um produto? Se não, o que se enquadraria e o porquê?

Answer (score 3):

Produto é tudo que pode ser produzido. Estou entendendo que a Automação não é apenas um serviço, mas peças que farão esse serviço, nesse caso se enquadrando como produto.

> produto substantivo masculino
>
> 1. aquilo que é produzido; resultado da produção.
> 2. aquilo que é produzido para venda no mercado. "p. agrícola, industrial"
> 3. resultado de um trabalho ou de uma atividade. "p. intelectual"
> 4. quantia apurada em um negócio, venda de alguma coisa etc.; féria, resultado. "aplicou o p. da venda num negócio"
> 5. arit resultado da multiplicação.
> 6. econ valor global da produção de bens e serviços num país, em determinado período.
> 7. mat m.q. INTERSEÇÃO ('conjunto'). Origem ⊙ ETIM lat. productus,a,um 'levado para diante, alongado, desenvolvido etc.'

Fonte: [Dicionário do Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=Dicion%C3%A1rio#dobs=produto)

Mesmo assim, se é apenas um serviço, na visão de Marketing, podemos considerar um produto não material ou serviço:

> Para o marketing, um produto é um objecto que é
>   colocado/disponibilizado num mercado com a intenção de satisfazer
>   aquilo de que necessita ou que deseja um consumidor. Neste sentido, o
>   produto transcende a sua própria condição física e inclui a percepção
>   sentida pelo consumidor aquando da aquisição/compra (atributos
>   simbólicos, psicológicos, etc.). O **produto não material**, por sua vez,
>   denomina-se serviço. Por exemplo: um computador e um modem são
>   produtos; a conexão à Internet é um serviço.

Fonte: [Conceito](https://conceito.de/produto)

Um outra opção para esse caso específico é trocar a denominação de Produto por Item de Venda. Nesse caso, poderia ser um serviço ou produto.

Comment: Andámos a trabalhar ao mesmo tempo :). Um serviço é um produto, mesmo fora do contexto do marketing; enquadra-se logo na aceção 1, 'que é produzido, resultado de produção'.

Answer (score 2):

Na linguagem económica, o processo de automatizar é um **serviço e um produto**; as peças e máquinas usadas nesse sistema são **bens** e também **produtos**. Em economia, um produto pode ser um bem ou um serviço. Um bem é um produto tangível, como cortinas, argolas, máquinas, etc. Um serviço é um produto intangível, como limpeza de cortinas, instalação de uma máquina (distintamente do fabrico do mesma), ou conceção e desenvolvimento dessa máquina.

Na linguagem corrente, *produto* é mais imediatamente associado a bem do que a serviço. Isto reflete-se nos dicionários, onde no verbete *produto* encontras a aceção que corresponde diretamente a bem [(aceção 2 do Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/produto), mas a noção de serviço vem apenas implícita na noção mais geral de produto [(aceção 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/produto):

> 1. Aquilo que é resultado de uma atividade humana ou de processo natural (produto industrial; produto intelectual); PRODUÇÃO
> 2. Coisa ou objeto produzidos como bem de consumo ou de comércio; ARTIGO; MERCADORIA

No entanto, do ponto de vista económico, ambos utilizam recursos, como trabalho, terra, etc. para satisfazer uma necessidade humana, e é isso que os torna um **produto**.

No entanto no teu caso concreto, *automação* parece referir-se na verdade a *peças para automação*. Peças são bens, porque são tangíveis. A conceção, desenvolvimento e instalação de um sistema automático é que seriam serviços.

A Wikipédia tem um artigo sobre a [*produto* em economia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produ%C3%A7%C3%A3o#Os_produtos) e outro sobre [*produto* no marketing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_(marketing)), em que a noção é um pouco diferente (no fundo, qualquer coisa, pessoa, ou entidade que possa ser promovida).